# Query MySQL updating records in a table joining onto a temporary table

Tags: mysql

Hi I have list of 3000 id's in a temp table called `Keepers`. I need to join to the `Accounts` table to do an inner join like the following:

```
select * from keepers a
join accounts_cstm b
on a.keepers_id=b.id_c
```

What I want to do is create an update query to where I update `keepers_c` in the `accounts_cstm` to flag the 3000 records as keepers. I want to automate the query so it uses the row number in my keepers table to update the `account_cstm`.`id_c` using mysql been trying to look at many way but it's not been easy.

Keepers Table

```
Row_Number  keepers_id
1   84d70138-161e-8033-6a19-53d260aa8309
2   103941fc-481e-7c58-1726-53cfc779c6fd
3   9a70736d-3971-a873-ee3e-53d259975dd2
4   346a27d7-47f8-953f-448e-53cfc97ae3ae
5   ebb7aab5-ab5b-ebf9-0cfc-53cfc81a99b9
```

Accounts table

```
# id_c  email_c title_c firstname_c lastname_c   keeper_c
9378d06d-5e6e-ce46-2549-53d012f43e44    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
ebb7aab5-ab5b-ebf9-0cfc-53cfc81a99b9    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    KEEPER
346a27d7-47f8-953f-448e-53cfc97ae3ae    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
d8480e38-dd8b-f3c9-e947-53d2601a3a2e    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    KEEPER
9a70736d-3971-a873-ee3e-53d259975dd2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    KEEPER
b4bd7137-eb35-bc48-67c6-53e943f02042    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
103941fc-481e-7c58-1726-53cfc779c6fd    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    KEEPER
f042b165-794b-80a9-7643-53d43337c454    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
124fc26a-5ba2-1e77-c4d5-54b31292fc68    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
6638375b-578d-c17f-7a12-5539796e9774    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
84d70138-161e-8033-6a19-53d260aa8309    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    KEEPER
```

Comment: Could you post the columns for both tables?

Comment: In addition, sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Keepers Columns: Row_Number, Account_Keepers_Id

Comment: Accounts_cstm columns: id_c, keeper_c, Email_c, Title_c, Firstname_c, Lastname_c

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is:

```
UPDATE keepers a
INNER JOIN accounts_cstm b ON a.keepers_id=b.id_c
SET b.keeper_c = a.row_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need the `Row_Number` column. Based on the sample data, I assume you want matches to set the value of `keeper_c` to `'KEEPER'`. Please let me know if this solution works for you:

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm a INNER JOIN keepers k ON a.id_c = k.id_c
   SET a.keeper_c = 'KEEPER'
;
```